# NRF SDK 1.8 - CONFIG_BOOTLOADER_MCUBOOT makes fail build process

Tags: c, zephyr-rtos

I want to use fota library, i enabled MCUBOOT but my program won't build after that. I'm using NRF SDK 1.8 with Zephyr 2.7.0

That's what i get :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/ABC/workspace_visual_studio/project_Sc/iris_project_Sc/external/sdk/zephyr/scripts/zephyr_module.py", line 486, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:/Users/ABC/workspace_visual_studio/project_Sc/iris_project_Sc/external/sdk/zephyr/scripts/zephyr_module.py", line 480, in main
        meta = process_meta(args.zephyr_base, west_proj, modules)
      File "C:/Users/ABC/workspace_visual_studio/project_Sc/iris_project_Sc/external/sdk/zephyr/scripts/zephyr_module.py", line 298, in process_meta
        'revision': git_revision(project_path)}
      File "C:/Users/ABC/workspace_visual_studio/project_Sc/iris_project_Sc/external/sdk/zephyr/scripts/zephyr_module.py", line 263, in git_revision
        rc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'rev-parse', '--is-inside-work-tree'],
      File "subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
      File "subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Nom de répertoire non valide
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you enabled mcumgr for your project ?
Have you added all the required configuration in your prj.conf file ?
it would be better if you elaborate on your build logs.

for folder structure you can refer this.[Overlay folder structure](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/83402/ncs1-8-0-52840-mcuboot-spi-external-flash-can-t-build-pass)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31933250)